# Date formatting in word by selecting a no. of cells in table

Tags: vba, ms-word

My requirement is that I want change the Date format of selected cells in a table in word document. I tried below code. I am able to change the Date Format if I select a single date. But, I am not able to change the Date Format for selected a no. of cells in a table. ....pls help

Code:

```
Sub ConvertDateFormat()
'
' Date formating
'

Dim oCl As Word.Cell
Dim oRng As Range
'
' Condition to check the selected data
'
  If Selection.Type = wdSelectionIP Or _
      Not Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
    MsgBox "Select a cell or range of cells before running" _
      & " this macro.", , "Nothing Selected"
    Exit Sub
  End If
  For Each oCl In Selection.Cells
    Set oRng = oCl.Range
    '
    'Drop of the end of cell mark
    '
    oRng.End = oRng.End - 1
    With oRng


    If IsDate(oRng) Then
        Selection.Text = Format(Selection.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd")
        Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Else ' not a date - end loop
        MsgBox ("Invalid Date Format")


    End If
        End With
      Next oCl
    lbl_Exit:

Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you try to change the text of the whole selection which contains several cells. So I think you have to replace that one line by

```
oRng.Text = Format(oRng.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

And I don't understand why you are collapsing the selection.